# How to use paginator separate and show page info in PrimeNG Table?

Tags: angular, primeng

To show custom page info in my [paginator](http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator) e.g. `Show {{startItem}} - {{endItem}} of {{totalRecords}}` I figured out that I need to use `currentPageReportTemplate` and a separate `paginator` in my PrimeNG Table. The thing is that I cannot make it communicate with my table.

My code:

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="ciConfig" [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand"
    [scrollable]="true" [(selection)]="mySelection" selectionMode="multiple" exportFilename="MessagesConfig"
    [showCurrentPageReport]="true">
  ...
</p-table>
<p-paginator [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20,50,100]"
 currentPageReportTemplate="Show {{startItem}} - {{endItem}} of {{totalRecords}}"
 (onPageChange)="paginate($event)>
</p-paginator>
```

Probably I will need to add `dropdownAppendTo` property of paginator but still can't find a way to make it work. Any idea?

Comment: I think you miss the [paginator]="false" property

Comment: Changed it and still nothing. @SoumyaGangamwar

Answer (score 1):

Add:

[showCurrentPageReport] = "true" currentPageReportTemplate = "my own template"

and it works.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator

Comment: would be great if you could show what is the structure of the `my own template`,